# google play game services - testing accounts login results in unknown error

Tags: android, google-play-services

I've followed the tutorials on how to implement the google play game services for android and have ended up with the simple google+ sign in. I tried how ever to login before I had fixed a problem. And now I can't login using this account, but I can if I use a different one.

The error I get with the first account is:

```
06-05 16:49:03.226: W/dqi(19754): Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {bearer=WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRequest", error=invalid_token}
06-05 16:49:03.226: E/Volley(19754): [4376] il.a: Unexpected response code 401 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/115167649949168063107
06-05 16:49:03.515: W/dqi(19754): Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {bearer=WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRequest", error=invalid_token}
06-05 16:49:03.515: E/Volley(19754): [4376] il.a: Unexpected response code 401 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/115167649949168063107
06-05 16:49:04.280: W/dqi(19754): Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {bearer=WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRequest", error=invalid_token}
06-05 16:49:04.280: E/Volley(19754): [4375] il.a: Unexpected response code 401 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/115167649949168063107
06-05 16:49:04.593: W/dqi(19754): Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {bearer=WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRequest", error=invalid_token}
06-05 16:49:04.593: E/Volley(19754): [4375] il.a: Unexpected response code 401 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/115167649949168063107
06-05 16:49:04.648: E/SignInIntentService(19754): User has not completed registration.
06-05 16:49:04.648: E/SignInIntentService(19754): aol
06-05 16:49:04.648: E/SignInIntentService(19754):   at ajy.a(SourceFile:108)
06-05 16:49:04.648: E/SignInIntentService(19754):   at abm.a(SourceFile:213)
06-05 16:49:04.648: E/SignInIntentService(19754):   at abm.a(SourceFile:194)
06-05 16:49:04.648: E/SignInIntentService(19754):   at aav.a(SourceFile:486)
06-05 16:49:04.648: E/SignInIntentService(19754):   at aqu.a(SourceFile:221)
06-05 16:49:04.648: E/SignInIntentService(19754):   at com.google.android.gms.games.service.GamesSignInIntentService.onHandleIntent(SourceFile:343)
06-05 16:49:04.648: E/SignInIntentService(19754):   at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
06-05 16:49:04.648: E/SignInIntentService(19754):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-05 16:49:04.648: E/SignInIntentService(19754):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-05 16:49:04.648: E/SignInIntentService(19754):   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Which results with the little dialog that says unknown error.

My guess is that its some cache stored somewhere for this app when I authorised it to use my G+ account. How can I revert this so it works with my first account again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try going to your Google+ settings on your device and purging the access that you had granted the app. Afterwards, MANUALLY set up Google+ for your test account, either through a PC/Mac web browser or through your device, then try re-linking the app. This worked for me.

Exact steps for Samsung Galaxy S3:

Settings -> Google -> Google+ -> Apps with Google+ Sign-In -> tap the app and at the bottom, tap Disconnect App.

For what it’s worth, I also tapped the option to “Delete all activity for this app” as well when I deleted it.

Comment: Thanks. This worked straight away. No need to set up Google+ Manually afterwards. Just deleted all about the app in Google+ on the phone.

Comment: Thank you for this. I'd tried just about every other possible option I could find, but disconnecting the app in the Google+ settings sorted it. Wish I'd read this a day ago :)

Comment: Thanks mate ! I've been stuck for hours on this one :s

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get my own leaderboard into production last night. The error you are describing is one that I (and judging by other comments that I have seen in error reports on SO ) and other people have also encountered. I found that I was unable to use the google account that I user in the developer console to sign on, even though it is explicitly listed as a testing account for the game. I tried shutting down the emulator etc. but I have never been able to get it to work. I used a different account and I was able to sign on. I do not know what the problem is with my developer console account - I also use it in Google Plus without problems. Incidentally, I am still unable to use my developer account on the production app with a real device.

My advice is to use a separate account for testing. Good luck !

Comment: I haven't tried with my developer account yet. The one not working isn't the developer account which is strange and makes less sense. 
But did you try to login in you app before you were finished implementing play services?

Answer (score 1):

This kind of problem is usually a Client ID setup issue. There probably is a mismatch between your Client ID setup, your package name and the certificate you are using to sign the app. In any event, follow our troubleshooting guide step by step, and it should take you to the solution:

https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting.html

Comment: I have the same issue as just_user and I followed your troubleshooting page with no luck.

Comment: I managed to get it work with a non-developper account. When I'm using my account I still get this error message...

Comment: Just ran into the same problem with Android Studio -- I had adjusted the package in the AndroidManifest.xml, but it was still wrong in the .gradle file, where it seems to be duplicated for some reason... :-/