# How to test Google Play Game Services using our developer account?

Tags: google-play-games

According to https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/testpub#enabling_accounts_for_testing it is mandatory to add ourselves to the list of testers otherwise that won't work.

However, in fact, I can only authenticate using test accounts that are not developer accounts, even after adding the developers to the list of test accounts. Am I doing something wrong?

The error is the same as in [google play game services - testing accounts login results in unknown error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943237/google-play-game-services-testing-accounts-login-results-in-unknown-error) but the given solution is not working. It only works with non-developer accounts.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem and I ignored it for several weeks (I used a separate account for testing). Eventually, I realised that the developer account did not have Google + enabled on it.
When I enabled Google + (having previously added the developer account to the list of testers) I was then able to use it for testing.

I think this is mentioned in the "top 7 developer mistakes video" (seven deadly sins?)

https://developers.google.com/live/shows/5936979195723776

Hope this helps !

Comment: My developer account is my primary account. I use it on G+ since the beginning. Same for the other dev.