# Failed to sign in error in google play games

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play-services

**Failed to sign in. Please check your network connection and try again.**

I have MainActivity, and have activity Board_Multiplayer_sample
MainActivity has button , where use have button to click to start the game.

> I have linked and authorized my game with SHA-1 in Google Play Developer Console.
>
> I added app id into ids.xml and I added meta tag to Android Manifest.
>   I have added Internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml
>
> I test and debug app from Android Studio with physical device and ofc there is my own gmail added as test user in Google Play Developer Console.

Comment: nothing related to code I guess...normal internet connection..

Comment: Internet working fine, there showing error code 401 (Sign_in required)

Answer (score 0):

If you still get some errors after following steps in [Troubleshooting Issues in Your Android Game](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting#top_of_page), kindly try going through these:

> Settings -> Google -> Google+ -> Apps with Google+ Sign-In -> tap the app and at the bottom, tap Disconnect App.

and

> also tap the option to “Delete all activity for this app”.

as suggested in SO post - [google play game services - testing accounts login results in unknown error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943237/google-play-game-services-testing-accounts-login-results-in-unknown-error).